# Can enums be replaced by consts in C?

Tags: c, enums

In C, even the following code gives an error (because of `orange`):

```
enum color {yellow, blue, green, red, brown, black, white, purple, orange};
enum fruit {cherry, apple, pear, melon, banana, strawberry, raspberry, orange};
```

But code like this:

```
enum fruit {cherry = 1, apple = 2, pear = 3, melon = 4, banana = 5, strawberry = 6, raspberry = 7, orange = 8};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  enum fruit f;
  int x;

  x = apple;
  f = -7;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiles with `gcc --std=c89 -pedantic`.

It seems `enum`s can be easily replaced by `const` variables:

```
typedef int fruit;
const fruit cherry = 1, apple = 2, pear = 3, melon = 4, banana = 5, strawberry = 6, raspberry = 7, orange = 8;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  fruit f;
  int x;

  x = apple;
  f = -7;

  return 0;
}
```

The ***only*** way `enum` behaves differently isthat you absolutely can't change the value of `cherry, apple, ...`, while with using `const`s one might try the usual tricks like `int *y = &apple; *y = -7;` (with `gcc` I get a warning, but it compiles).

Is this the only difference or have I missed anything?

Comment: `const fruit apple = 1; int *y = &apple; *y = -7;`. Undefined behavior is what you get for modifying a `const` variable. **Edit**: Apparently, it's rather called a "constraint violation", and a C implementation is required to warn about this.

Comment: What's the point of declaring it `const` if you intend to modify it?

Comment: A better question would be, why is `const` needed when you could just use `enum` constants (which are guaranteed to produce as efficient machine code as literal numbers, while with `const` values this depends on optimizations).

Comment: The question was closed as I was composing an answer. Two big advantages of `enum` are (a) the constants are automatically given sequential values, and (b) given `const fruit cherry = 1;`, the name `cherry` is not a constant expression. (`const` means read-only, not constant.) Furthermore, the declared `const` objects "pollute" the global namespace in exactly the same way that enumeration constants do.

Comment: Enums are just integers that the compiler can check to ensure you're using the right value with the right type. Enums can be abused since you can easily store a value in an enum type at runtime that isn't one of your named types, so they are really only good for compile time checks.

Worrying about polluting the global namespace is an issue. If you have the luxury of using C++ over C then you can use namespaces, wrap your enum within a struct, or in C++11 use the `enum class` construction.

Comment: @KemyLand: Directly modifying a `const`-qualified object is a constraint violation. You can indirectly attempt to modify it, for example using a pointer cast: `*(fruit*)apple = -7;` -- that has undefined behavior.

Comment: @JacobStatnekov: Enums don't check that you're using the right type. Enumeration types are assignment-compatible with any numeric type (`enum fruit nonsense = 1.5;`), and the constants themselves are of type `int`, not of the `enum` type.

Comment: @axiac: I don't *intend* to modify it. This question is about *differences* between `enum` and `const`.

Comment: @KeithThompson your point is exactly what I meant by my second sentence. My first sentence meant you would get a compiler error if you wrote   Fruit GetFruit(){return 1;} (I'm now on mobile and can't seem to access the tilde character, so that method returning Fruit is probably hard to read.)

Comment: @JacobStatnekov: No, `Fruit GetFruit(){return 1;}` is perfectly legal and compiles without error. (C++ has different rules, but the question is about C.)

Comment: Voting to reopen the question. There are significant differences between `enum` constants and `const`-qualified objects.

Comment: You are comparing apples and bananas (oranges have too much in common with apples already). `enum`s are datatypes, `const` is a qualifier you can also apply to an `enum`. And C does not have constants other than literals (e.g. `1`) or _enum-constants_. Try `enum { L = 9 }; int a[L];` vs. `const int L = 9; ...`

Comment: @KeithThompson a good point on a difference between C and C++, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @JacobStatnekov: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. And C++ is a very different language. Don't make assumptions about the semantics of C based on C++.

Comment: C++11-style strongly-typed enums [have been proposed for inclusion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2008.pdf) in C2x, by the way.

Comment: @Olaf yes I know there are no methods in C. Please excuse my having used the wrong word

Comment: @JacobStatnekov: Problem is that is read by beginners and this question is already dealing with confusion beteen C++ and C. _methods_ just have additional semantics in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several significant differences between `enum` constants and `const`-qualified objects.

An `enum` type declaration such as

```
enum fruit {cherry, apple, pear};
```

automatically associates sequential values starting with `0` to the constants `cherry`, `apple`, and `pear`. (You can override these values if you like.) Which means that (a) you can rearrange the constants as you like and the compiler will take care of the values, and (b) there's less risk of accidentally using incorrect values.

An alternative such as:

```
const int cherry = 0;
const int apple = 1;
const int pear = 2;
```

is more difficult to maintain -- and, perhaps most importantly, the names `cherry` et al *are not constant expressions*. That means, for example, that you can't use them in case labels or in any other context requiring a constant expression.

As for changing the value of a `const`-qualified object, doing so directly is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. (gcc tends to make such diagnostics non-fatal warnings by default.) You can attempt to change it indirectly, for examlpe by using a pointer cast, but that has undefined behavior.

One thing to remember about C's `enum` types is that the constants are of type `int`, *not* of the enumerated type. Usually this doesn't matter, since the value will be implicitly converted to the right type in most contexts. (C++ has different rules, but the question is about C.)

Answer (score 0):

`enum` is usually used as logical variables as you mentioned in your example, such as `color` and `fruit` where you don't really care about the actual numerical value of each element but rather on what it represents.

`const` on the other hand, is normally used when you actually care about the numerical value. For instance:

```
const float PI = 3.1415926;
```

So as for your question, the answer is yes, enum can be replaced by const values, but the question is if there is a true use-case for it